# Not receiving "keyboardWillHide" event on Android with React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to dock a view to the top of the keyboard on iOS and Android. I've currently got this working with `DeviceEventEmitter`, but I never receive the `keyboardWillHide` event on Android. Is this expected behavior or is this a bug in `DeviceEventEmitter`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Android `react-native` code only implements the `keyboardDidShow` and `keyboardDidHide` methods.

Source: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/7377fdcc70b25eb023e7c6d1b37eeae2a700cb88/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/ReactRootView.java#L401-L416